# Explain win.attribute()

Tags: python, tkinter

I dont know the purpose of win.attributes('-topmost', 1) because when we create win,it's the second window and it's on top. Does two line work similarly ? And what do they use win.attributes('-fullscreen', 1) for?

```
 win = tk.Toplevel()
 win.attributes('-fullscreen', 1)
 win.attributes('-topmost', 1)
```

Comment: What have you done to find out?

Comment: I don't know about you but `-fullscreen` seems kinda self-explanatory and `-topmost`... well you would notice the behavior if you let the program run for a while while you were doing other things on the computer

Comment: Thanks a lot for all of your comments. I have just hide each line and run, so I realize that -fullscreen use for make the window fullscreen and when open the second window  it means when i click outside the frame it won't get hide (about -topmost). I just  wonder that when win is set to fullscreen , it means I can't interact with outside frame, so -topmost is unnecessary, is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Different platforms (windows, OSX, linux, etc) support different sets of attributes for windows. This lets you set those platform-specific attributes. They are specified with a leading dash, I think, because the tkinter developers were lazy. This function just directly passes all arguments to the underlying `wm attributes` command.

The canonical list of attributes can be found in the [tcl/tk documentation for the wm attributes command](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6.11/TkCmd/wm.htm#M7)

> Does two line work similarly ?

The two lines that you specifically call out do two different things.

Setting the `-fullscreen` option makes the window fill the full screen. From the documentation:

*"Places the window in a mode that takes up the entire screen, has no borders, and covers the general use area (i.e. Start menu and taskbar on Windows, dock and menubar on OSX, general window decorations on X11)."*

Setting the `-topmost` option forces the window to be on top of other windows, no matter what size it is. From the documentation:

*"Specifies whether this is a topmost window (displays above all other windows)."*

Comment: I just wonder that when win is set to fullscreen , it means I can't interact with outside frame  so win can't not hide, that's why -topmost is unnecessary, is that right?

Comment: @LyNguyen what do you mean by that? either how, `"-topmost"` is necessary when you want to keep a window on top (even if it is out of focus) of all other open windows (except maybe some other windows that are run by other programs that are fullscreen or also set to topmost). To maybe understand better if you set both the `"-fullscreen"` AND `"-topmost"` you basically will lock yourself out of other windows (the only thing you will be able to access will be the taskbar by alt-tabbing)